# Maximum visa-free stay in Singapore for UK citizens

Tags: visas, uk-citizens, singapore

I've come across conflicting advice online for UK entry requirements to Singapore: the official [UK Foreign Office website](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/singapore/entry-requirements) says that stays of up to 90 days' duration are allowed without a visa, but the [Singaporean Ministry of Foreign Affairs](https://www.mfa.gov.sg/content/mfa/overseasmission/london/visa_information/overview.html) list 30 days' on their website.

In addition, neither provides any information on how many such visits are possible in a year, which is important for me, since I would like to travel to nearby countries during my stay, and possible return for another long period during this calendar year.

Does anyone know of any reliable (preferable official) online resources that would set the record straight, or have personal experience of navigating this system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Both souces are correct**: per Timatic, a UK passport allows 30 days visa free,  but if you have proof of abode in the EU, that's extended to 90 days. http://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/countryinfo.html

Singapore does not publish guidance on how many visits per year or how many days per year are allowed.  However, given how small the country is, you can expected some pretty pointed questioning if you return for a 2nd or 3rd long stay and may be denied entry unless you can demonstrate that you're not working illegally.  If you're staying with a girlfriend or family, I'd advise you to get a Long-Term Social Visit Pass instead.

Comment: I had no idea about the SVP, you have in fact accurately guessed my situation. Checking on the MoM website though, it sounds like it might be restricted to family / spouse, but I'll certainly follow it up.